# Regarding the question after the CURD Update test, This mail box already exists in the Store

Tags: python

Regarding the question after the CURD Update test,
The bottom is my program. I create the editing part but when I want to save it after editing, it will keep reminding me that the email part is duplicated, but if I have id=5 (http://127.0.0.1:5757/polls) /5/edit/) Edit, but if I change the email, it will be a new ID after the update. How can I change it? Could you please remind me which error is wrong?

**error message: This mail box already exists in the Store.**

ps: You can read the pictures to understand the situation first.

[update test Before modification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlKk7.png): Before the modification, my content was empty .
[update test after modification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkKg6.png) : After the modification, I fill in the text into the content field, it will show that This mail box already exists in the Store.

```
--models.py-- 

class Store(models.Model):  
  store_name = models.CharField(max_length=10) 
  store_holder = models.CharField(max_length=50) 
  store_phoneNumber = models.CharField(max_length=10)  
  store_address = models.CharField(max_length=100) 
▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼▼
  store_email = models.EmailField(max_length=60,
                                  default='',
                                  help_text='need u', verbose_name='email account',
                                  unique=True, )
▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲
  store_notes = models.TextField(blank=True, default='')  

  def __str__(self):
    return self.store_name

  def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('polls:polls_detail', kwargs={'id': self.id})
```

```
--froms.py--

from django import forms
from .models import *
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm

class StoreForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Store
    fields = '__all__'
```

```
--views.py--

def polls_edit(request, id=None):
  # basic use permissions 
  if not request.user.is_staff or not request.user.is_superuser:
    raise Http404

  instance = get_object_or_404(Store, id=id)
  form = StoreForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=instance)

  if form.is_valid():
    instance = form.save(commit=False)
    instance.save()
    # message success
    return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())

  context = {
    'title': 'edit',
    'instance': instance,
    'form': form,
  }
  return render(request, 'polls/polls_form.html', context)
```

```
--urls.py--
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_view

# Create your urls here.
app_name = 'polls'

urlpatterns = [

  path('profile/', views.polls_profile, name='polls_profile'),  # http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/list
  path('edit/', views.polls_profile_edit, name='polls_profile_edit'),  # http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/3/edit/
  path('changePassword/', views.changePassword, name='changePassword'),  # http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/3/edit/

  # CURD
  path('<int:id>/detail/', views.polls_detail, name='polls_detail'),  # http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/9/
  path('create/', views.polls_create, name='polls_create'),  # http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/create
  path('list/', views.polls_list, name='polls_list'),  # http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/list
  path('<int:id>/edit/', views.polls_edit, name='polls_edit'),  # http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/3/edit/
  # path('<int:id>/delete/', views.polls_delete, name='polls_delete'),  # http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/delete
  path('delete/', views.polls_delete, name='polls_delete'),  # http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/delete

  # else views
  path('contact/', views.contact, name='contact'),
  # path('', views.login_redirect, name='login_redirect'),
  # path('register/', views.registration_view, name='register'),
  path('register/', views.register, name='register'),
  path('', views.starter, name='starter'),





  path('login/', auth_view.LoginView.as_view(template_name='registration/login.html'), name='login'),
  path('logout/', auth_view.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='registration/logged_out.html'), name='logout'),

  # pw change
  path('password_change/', auth_view.PasswordChangeView.as_view(), name='password_change'),
  # pw change success
  path('password_change/done/', auth_view.PasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(), name='password_change_done'),



  # forget pw / set pw
  path('password_reset/', auth_view.PasswordResetView.as_view(), name='password_reset'),
  # forget pw / set pw success
  path('password_reset/done/', auth_view.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), name='password_reset_done'),
  #
  path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth_view.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),
  # pw already change
  path('reset/done/', auth_view.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(), name='password_reset_complete'),
  # pw sent
  # path('reset_password_sent/', auth_view.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(), name='password_reset_complete'),
]
```

```
--polls_forms.html

{% extends 'base_generic.html' %}

{% block body %}
  <title>Form Page</title>
  <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
  <div class='content-wrapper'>
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
      <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
      <div class='content-header'>
        <div class='container-fluid'>
          <div class='row mb-2'>
            <div class='col-sm-6'>
              <h1 class='m-0'>Form Page</h1>
            </div><!-- /.col -->
            <div class='col-sm-6'>
              <ol class='breadcrumb float-sm-right'>
                <li class='breadcrumb-item'><a href='#'>Form</a></li>
                <li class='breadcrumb-item active'>Form Page</li>
              </ol>
            </div><!-- /.col -->
          </div><!-- /.row -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.content-header -->

      <!-- Main content -->
      <div class='content'>
        <div class='container-fluid'>
          <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-lg-6'>
              <div class='card'>
                <div class='card-body'>

                  <h1>Test</h1>
                  <form method='post' action='{% url 'polls:polls_create' %}'>
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ form.as_p }}
                    <input type='submit' value='save'>
                  </form>


                  <div class='main'>
                    <!-- Display attributes of instance -->
                    {{ data.city }} <br/>
                    {{ data.description }}
                  </div>

                  <h5 class='card-title'>user account : {{ user|capfirst }}</h5><br>
                  {% if author_list %}
                    <ul>

                      {% for author in author_list %}
                        <li>
                          <a href='{{ author.get_absolute_url }}'>
                            {{ author }} ({{ author.date_of_birth }} -
                            {% if author.date_of_death %}{{ author.date_of_death }}{% endif %})
                          </a>
                        </li>
                      {% endfor %}

                    </ul>
                  {% else %}
                    <p>There are no authors available.</p>
                  {% endif %}

                </div>
                <!-- /* card-body -->
              </div>

            </div>
            <!-- /.col-md-6 -->

          </div>
          <!-- /.row -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.content -->
    {% else %}
      <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
      <div class='content-wrapper pt-5'>
        <h4>Register</h4>
      </div>
      <!-- /.content-wrapper -->
    {% endif %}
  </div>
  <!-- /.content-wrapper -->

{% endblock %}
```

```
--settings.py--

import os
from pathlib import Path

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-7r4mj*$^bv(zj@#+$d42&k$ax_6ps3*f=wc8f)96s1yn3!%^4$'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
  'django.contrib.admin',
  'django.contrib.auth',
  'django.contrib.contenttypes',
  'django.contrib.sessions',
  'django.contrib.messages',
  'django.contrib.staticfiles',

  'polls',
  'accounts',
  'shops',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
  'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
  {
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
      'context_processors': [
        'django.template.context_processors.debug',
        'django.template.context_processors.request',
        'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
        'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
      ],
    },
  },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
  'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'restA_db',
    'USER': 'postgres',
    'PASSWORD': 'postgres5',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '5432',
  }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
  {
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
  },
  {
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
  },
  {
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
  },
  {
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
  },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'zh-Hant'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Taipei'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
# STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_cdn')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
  '/var/www/static/', 
]

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/dist/media_cdn')


DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

# Redirect to home URL after login (Default redirects to /accounts/profile/)
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/polls/'
LOGIN_URL = '/accounts/login/'
# LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/accounts/logout/'

# crispy_forms
# CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

# STMP Configuration
if DEBUG:
  EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = '587'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'georgiawang5332@gmail.com'  # sender account
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '0704gta93julro'  # sender password


--urls.py--

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
# from django.contrib.auth.views import login, logout

urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('shops/', include('shops.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)  

#Add URL maps to redirect the base URL to our application
from django.views.generic import RedirectView
urlpatterns += [
    path('', RedirectView.as_view(url='/polls/', permanent=True)),
]


# Add Django site authentication urls (for login, logout, password management)
urlpatterns += [
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
  urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) ]
  urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```